# ¿Cómo aplicar esto en un DF?

Tags: python, dataframe

Estoy tratando de aplicar una función en un dataframe, pero no sé como insertarlo. Os comento. Sé como eliminar el texto que sigue un símbolo hasta el primer espacio en una cadena. Con ejemplo será más claro:

*"Esto es un @maldito ejemplo"*

Lo que quiero es obtener esto:

*"Esto es un ejemplo"*

Como veis, elimino el texto que sigue al @ hasta el primer espacio. Sin embargo, no sé como aplicarlo en un dataframe. Quiero aplicar la solución en toda una columna, sustituyendo su contenido.

```
import re
s = 'Esto es un @maldito ejemplo'
print re.sub('@\S+', '', s)
```

La salida: 
Esto es un ejemplo

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? 
Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola Marc, no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta, pero dado que aparentemente usas Python 2, si no hay causa de fuerza mayor, considera dejar de usarlo y pasarte a Python 3. Python 2 está en EOL desde Enero, no va a recibir correcciones de seguridad ni de bugs ni mucho menos nuevas características. La gran mayoría de bibliotecas de importancia [han dejado o van a dejar de dar soporte en las nuevas versiones](https://python3statement.org/)  a su vez a Python 2 (Pandas y NumPy incluidas).

Comment: Hola FJ Sevilla, y muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ha sido perfecta. Lo cierto es que estoy usando Python 3, aunque buscando por internet una solución al problema que tenía terminé viendo fragmentos de código (los que has visto) que me parecían un posible paso previo para la solución que buscaba. Aun así, muchas gracias por tu sugerencia, y gracias de nuevo por tu respuesta. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas ofrece versiones de los métodos de la clase `str` de Python  que trabajan de forma vectorizada mediante [`pandas.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html). En éste caso tienes que usar [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Foo": ("Esto es un @maldito ejemplo",
                          "Esto es un @maldito",
                          "Esto es otra cosa",
                          "y esto es @enredarlo@ más")}
                  )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>                            Foo
> 0  Esto es un @maldito ejemplo
> 1          Esto es un @maldito
> 2            Esto es otra cosa
> 3    y esto es @enredarlo@ más
>
> >>> df["Foo"].str.replace('@\S+', '')
>
> 0    Esto es un  ejemplo
> 1            Esto es un 
> 2      Esto es otra cosa
> 3         y esto es  más
> Name: Foo, dtype: object
> ```

Es decir, para aplicar la substitución a lo largo de toda la columna y modificarla en el DataFrame debes hacer:

```
df["Foo"] = df["Foo"].str.replace('@\S+', '')
```

Comment: Impecable, ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

una forma eficiente seria:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

s = 'Esto es un @maldito ejemplo'

d = {"example":[s,s,s,s,s]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df = df["example"].apply(lambda x: re.sub('@\S+', '', s))
```

Comment: Por favor, visita el apartado de SO sobre lo que se considera un buena respuesta. Comaprto el enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . De no modificarla puede ser eliminada. Gracias